# Django classed based views and inheritance

Tags: python, django

I'm setting up my layout in Django using functional views but decide to change it out for classes. I'm a bit lost as to how I can get the information from the views into my template however.

My first attempt was below

```
class Menu(generic.ListView):
  model = Categories
  template_name = 'portfolio/layout.html'
  context_object_name = 'category_list'
  # def get_queryset(self):
    # return Categories.objects.all()

class IndexView(Menu):
  template_name = 'portfolio/index.html'
```

This allowed me to set up layout.html with my menu items by iterating through "category_list". The menu items carried over in index.html that extended layout.html

After doing a bit more research, I decided to set up my views as follows:

```
class MenuView(object):
  def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
    context = super(MenuView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
    context['menu'] = Categories.objects.all()

    return context

class LayoutView(generic.TemplateView):
  template_name = 'portfolio/layout.html'
```

I'm still getting my head around how this works, but according to this tutorial (https://blog.safaribooksonline.com/2013/10/28/class-based-views-in-django/) I think I am updating the get_context_data function to include my query for the Categories model. I can't figure out how to access context['menu'] to display into my template however.

Answer (score 2):

Your `MenuView` class should be a subclass of one of the class-based view classes rather than `object` - which one depends on what behavior you're expecting. Possibly `TemplateView` if you just want to display a template with context information.

Accessing context variables in the template works the same way whether the context was built by a functional view or a class-based view - your queryset of categories will be available as `{{ menu }}`, or you can iterate through with `{% for category in menu %}`, etc.